# Is it possible to fetch a local JSON file using Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, backbone.js

I am trying to fetch a local JSON file using Backbone js. The JSON looks really simple and validated one.
Here is the Backbone.js code snippet:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name: '',
        age: 0
    }
});

MyCollection =Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: "myJSON.json"
});

MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection = new MyCollection(),

    initialize: function(){
        success: function() {
            console.log("success")
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
})
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Nikola",
        "age": 86
    },
    {
        "name": "Einstein",
        "age": 76
    }
]
```

On Chrome I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."
And on Firefox it just says "syntax error".

Is there any way to make it work without using a local server?

Comment: Sure, paste the JSON right into your code.

Comment: @Cymen, I meant without doing that also. Possible to fetch it from a local file? :)

Comment: No. You can paste it in or you can run a server. There are many simple ways to run a server. Why are you trying to not do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dropbox account and upload your json files there. Then you can use those links as a "server". I've used this before and it works fine.

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/123456789/myFile.json"
});
```

Really hacky, but eh.